# Backtrace in error handler not showing count() function call

Tags: php, error-handling, backtrace

I use `set_error_handler()` to set up an error handler within which I want to read the backtrace and get the name of a function where the error originated.

This works well for most built-in PHP functions which generate warnings. However when there is a `count()` function warning, the call entry of `count()` function doesn't appear in the backtrace at all. Instead the caller function `foo()` is immediately present in the backtrace. (Tested with PHP 7.4.)

Is there any reason for that and does any other built-in function behave like `count()`? (E.g. `array_key_exists()` behaves the same way.)

Playground: https://onlinephp.io/c/74421

```
<?php

set_error_handler(function () {
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    var_dump($backtrace[1]["function"]);
    return false;
});

function foo() {
    // warning - "array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given"
    // error handler dumps "array_map" -> GOOD
    array_map("intval", null);
  
    // warning - "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"
    // error handler dumps "foo" -> BAD (should dump "count")
    count(null);
}

foo();
```

Comment: Your playground shows the failure of `count` as expected. Both with older 7.4.x versions as well as 8.2.x.

Comment: @Dave It shows warnings as expected. But dumping `$backtrace[1]["function"]` isn't able to dump "count", however it is able to dump "array_map".

Comment: If `count` is `null` what is going to be dumped? It's a null set. On the other hand, the exception occurs before getting to `count` so it may not even be seen.

Comment: @Dave What is going to be dumped? See the `var_dump()` call in the error handler. Also, there is no exception occuring (in PHP 7.4), only warnings, so both `array_map()` and `count()` will be invoked.